# Can g++ / minGW play nice with the Windows SDK? Is Visual Studio the only option?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, g++, mingw

Can g++ and minGW on Windows XP use the Windows SDK?

Specifically, why does g++ fail to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) {
 printf("!!!Hello World!!!");
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have tried compiling by by running:

```
g++ -c -Wall  Test.cpp -IC:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Platform\ SDK/Include/
```

I get a litany of compile errors beginning with

```
winnt.h:666:2: #error Must define a target architecture.
```

I have installed the [Windows Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A55B6B43-E24F-4EA3-A93E-40C0EC4F68E5&displaylang=en#filelist)

### Background

I am working on a large real-time image processing software project that up until now has used g++, minGW and gnu make files (written by hand). For a new feature, I need to interface with a [frame grabber](http://www.bitflow.com/index.php/KarbonCL) that has an [SDK which was designed for Visual Studio](http://www.bitflow.com/index.php/SDK). The framegrabber SDK depends on header files from the Windows SDK.

Do I need to learn Visual Studio or is there another way?

Comment: But maybe he just wants to type "make"

Comment: This also seems to be a good reference: http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=670

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use MinGW to compile Windows programs every day, with zero problems. There must be something wrong with your installation - try the version at [Twilight Dragon Media](http://tdragon.net/recentgcc/).

**Edit:** Just re-read your post - you do not need to specify the include directory as you are doing, and probably should not do so. Also, you may (or may not) need the slightly mysterious **-mwindows** flag. I just compiled your program using  MinGW (TDM build) g++ 4.4.1, with the command line:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

with absolutely no problems.

**More Info:** Just so you know what the **-mwindows** flag does, the GCC docs say:

> This option is available for Cygwin and
>   MinGW targets.It specifes that a GUI
>   application is to be generated by
>   instructing the linker to set the
>   PE header subsystem type appropriately.

Personally, I've never found it necessary, but then my Windows apps are all command line tools or servers.

Comment: Why do you not need to specify the include directory? How does g++ know where the include files are? 

For example, when I include my framegrabber SDK my compiler complains that it can't find a crtDbg.h include file. That header file exists in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\crt\ but g++ doesn't seem to know about it.

Comment: MinGW GCC picks up the include files from its own include directory, which contains its own versions of the windows headers. If you need to specify a "non-standard" header then you may need to use the include path, but you should make sure it comes after the GCC default path. Also, you need to be a bit careful with the case of filenames if you want to write portable code - you should never use mixed case.

Comment: I see. Thanks. What is the order of precedence for including paths? Does a "-I" passed to the compiler override the GCC default path?

Comment: Also, if you want a happy life, install any extra headers and libraries in a path without any spaces in the directory names. Remember GCC is  a UNIX based tool chain, and UNIX users almost never create file names with spaces in them, so the tools have not been well tested on such names.

Comment: Can't remember what the precedence is - the GCC manual is available at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs.

Answer (score 4):

According to the discussions from the MinGW-users mailing list, you might encounter compatibility problems with the Windows SDK, and you may have to fix those problems yourself.

---

Georgi Petrov [Dec 27, 2010; 8:33am]:

> Hello,
>
> I'm trying to develop a EVR (Vista/7 specific video presentation API) 
>   renderer for MPlayer on MSYS/MinGW. The problem is that I have Windows
>   SDK v7.1 and I need evr.h from it. If I try to copy it to MinGW's 
>   include directory as well as the 12 header files it includes, the 
>   compilation is close to impossible. **I have a TON of errors just by 
>   including evr.h, nothing else. I investigated and found that I can't 
>   use the Windows SDK header files directly with MinGW, because it ships
>   with its own header files, which are sometimes very, very different.** 
>   The problem is that Media Foundation/Enhanced Video Renderer header 
>   files are not part of MinGW's header files.
>
> What should I do?

- Windows SDK header files question:

  http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Windows-SDK-header-files-question-td5870336.html

---

Ross Ridge [Oct 10, 2010; 10:16pm]:

> For the most part the Windows SDK headers aren't incompatible with
>   GCC.  If there one particular header file you need that doesn't exist
>   in  win32api heapers or is missing something you need, then you can
>   try  just using that one header with from the Windows SDK and use
>   win32api  for the rest.
>
> **It's also possible to only use Windows SDK headers, and avoid using
>   the  win32api headers entirely, but you need to fix a number of
>   problems in key  header files.  I used to just modify the headers, but
>   the Windows SDK  has actually gotten a bit more compatible and now I
>   use wrappers to fix  the problems.**
>
> **There are some header files and libraries that are pretty much 
>   fundementally incompatible with GCC, like GDI+.  If you want to use
>   GDI+,  you'll need to use a Microsoft compiler.**
>
> ```
>                                     Ross Ridge
> ```

- compiling against Windows SDK:

  http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/compiling-against-Windows-SDK-td5609389.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest version of **MSYS2 UCRT64 with MingW64**.  I'm using it on Windows 11.

Use '**pacman**' to install '**mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc**'.  Try re-installing it too to insure you have the WIN32 SDK which is included in this windows-based package:

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-12.2.0-6 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-12.2.0-6

Total Installed Size:  154.48 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                               [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                             [###############################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                  [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                            [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                          [###############################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc                      [###############################] 100%
```

I discovered the **windows.h** is located in '**/ucrt64/include**' within the shell session and '**C:\Msys64\ucrt64\include**' outside the shell:

```
$ find . -name windows.h
./mingw64/include/windows.h
./ucrt64/include/windows.h
```

Here's a link to an article from Microsoft which shows how to troubleshoot setting up gcc to work with building windows applications:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

You can add the directories to your build using the '**-I**' parameter on '**make**' or '**gcc**':

```
make -I /ucrt64/include
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding these defines before you include those windows headers

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```

EDIT: my gcc compiles your script without problems (and without these defines) aswell.
I am using mingw's gcc 4.40 (alpha ?!)

Comment: There is absolutely no need to do this.