# Compiler for Win32 Programs?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, compiler-construction

I'm going to start learning how to program applications for Windows. I'm not sure what compiler I should use. Right now I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE 10.5 and got used to it and would like to stick to it.

I don't know if I should use the GNU GCC compiler or the MSVC++ 2008 compiler. Is there any reason to pick one over the other when creating a Win32 GUI project?

And how can I tell the compiler/linker to look in the Windows SDK directory instead of it's own directory?

Comment: So, I'm assuming you want to compile C++ code?

Comment: yes c or c++. I'm know enough of it

Comment: You can use any of those with Code::Blocks. Pick the one you like the most.

Comment: I hope it's not argumentative anymore. There could be real objective reasons to pick one compiler over the other. Can you give a subjective, argumentative answer in favor of your favorite? Yes. Does that make the question any less valid?

Comment: The Visual C++ compiler is *probably* better for Win32 applications. It's at least been heavily optimized and stress-tested for that particular application. But GCC is a great compiler; you wouldn't go wrong either way.

Answer (score 7):

You can use any of those with Code::Blocks. Pick the one you like the most. As for telling the tools about the Windows SDK, right-click your project and pick "Build options...":

[image: The Build options dialog]

Add `<SDKPath>\include` (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include on my machine) to the compiler directories, and to linker directories add `<SDKPath>\lib` (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib on my machine)

Comment: If you run into trouble with MinGW, try the -mwindows flag suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022112/can-g-mingw-play-nice-with-the-windows-sdk-is-visual-studio-the-only-option/2022130#2022130).

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Visual Studio. You'll handly find anything better than this for Windows. You can also use comand line gcc / g++ from Cygwin console, but I still use VS as the code editor. You'll get VS2008 Express for free here:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

Comment: Why would you still download VS 2008 when you can get VS 2010 now for free?

Comment: I prefer 2008's "Visual" appearance. Both "Studios" are ok.

Answer (score 0):

For Win32 programs (and particularly GUI ones) I feel Visual Studio is a good choice. Sure, it has its share of shortcomings, but its quite good as a whole. Moreover you can pick up a free (and limited capability) copy of it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-All).

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with what most others are saying and would use Visual Studio. As pointed out the express version is free, but if you are a student you should look at the [Microsoft DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) program.