# C++ Win API function 'not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to use [GetNamedSecurityInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/aa376397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I  keep getting out of scope errors:

```
main.cpp:25:3: error: 'SDDL_REVISION_1' was not declared in this scope
   SDDL_REVISION_1, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, secDescBuffer, buflen);
   ^
main.cpp:25:68: error: 'ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor' was not declared in this scope
   SDDL_REVISION_1, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, secDescBuffer, buflen);
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "sddl.h"
#include "aclapi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PACL pACL = NULL;

    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecDesc = NULL;

    dwRes = GetNamedSecurityInfo(TEXT("C:\\somefile.txt"),
        SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        NULL, NULL, &pACL, NULL, &pSecDesc);

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == dwRes) {

        LPTSTR * secDescBuffer = NULL;
        PULONG buflen = NULL;

        dwRes = ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(pSecDesc,
            SDDL_REVISION_1, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, secDescBuffer, buflen);

    } else {
        printf("GetNamedSecurityInfo Error %lu\n", dwRes);
    }
    ...
```

I know it uses the sddl.h header, and it definitely exists with no compile errors referring directly to it. What am I missing here?

*edit:* I am using netbeans and minGW toolchain. I have the Windows SDK, and have been using other parts just fine (like GetNamedSecurityInfo as shown in the example).

Comment: 51 characters for one function name, sometimes they really overdo it...

Comment: I know right? I stared at it several times to make sure there was no typo.

Comment: Verbosity at its finest. Did you include the header and define WINVER & Co properly?

Comment: The header (to my knowledge) is sddl.h, which is included without errors. WINVER and such is defined by mingw (got warnings of redefining when I defined myself to check).

Comment: maybe missing WINVER macro definition?? try to `cout` it... or just add `#define WIN32` on top.

Comment: Normally you would `#include <sddl.h>` etc (i.e. angle brackets rather than quotes) for system headers.

Comment: Debugging headers is a pain. The only possible cause I can think of is that the header is broken or incompatible, or mingw is setting WINVER to the wrong values.

Comment: What version of the Windows SDK do you have? Does the sddl.h file you include contain the SDDL_REVISION_1 var? If so, check the #ifdef's around it.

Comment: Try to update MinGW, in the older versions these functions were missing.

Comment: FWIW, your code builds fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: This code works fine in MSVC :)

Comment: Generate a preprocessor file to see what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While many of the comments and Ben Key's answer led me to the right place, it came down to the fact that the *Min* in Mingw stands for minimal.

The `sddl.h` that I was using was actually coming from Mingw's include folder, not from my Windows SDK include. After looking at the [sddl.h provided by Mingw](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/686b9d21aa238718dc3c8073a4e768522a3d153d/tree/include/sddl.h), I noticed that it is a very minimal version, and is missing the prototypes and defines I need. This also explains why my code worked in MSVC for others.

Thank you all for the comments and answers that helped me figure this out!

Edit: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698858/2407079) to another question outlines some of the issues when using both mingw and Win SDK includes.

Edit2: As Ben Key mentioned in his comment, [mingw-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) has a version of `sddl.h` (and other includes) that is much more filled out than the one found in the original mingw. Mingw-builds is a merge with mingw-w64, and seems to be the most up-to-date (while still being mature) of the mingw options. You can read more about mingw-w64 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64).

Comment: The version of sddl.h that comes with the version of MinGW available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/ (GCC 4.8.1) has SDDL_REVISION_1 and ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor defined.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for showing me this, I've learned quite a bit through dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`SDDL_REVISION_1` is defined in `sddl.h`, but only if `WINAPI_FAMILY` is defined as `WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP`. The default value of `WINAPI_FAMILY` is apparently `WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP`, that is `winapifamily.h` defines it as `WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP` if it is not already defined.

My best guess is that you have defined `WINAPI_FAMILY` to something other than `WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP`.