# Eclipse and Windows Headers

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I'm using **Eclipse** CDT and have a c project that included standard windows header "**windows.h**". What do you suggest to resolve the following errors? I do not have access to these standard headers and I should not have. When I just include "windows.h" and compile the following errors appear in the error list while I have not referenced any of these headers. **MinGW** toolchain - CDT Internal is used. This pretty seems strange maybe I have to change the compiler?

**winnt.h**: #error Must define a target architecture.

**winnt.h**: unknown type name "EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION"

**propidl.h**: array type has incomplete element type

**excpt.h**: conflicting types for "EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD"

**wtypes.h**: expected specifier-qualifier-list before "/" token

**wtypes.h**: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token

**winioctl.h**: flexible array member in union

Comment: Which toolchain are you actually using?

Comment: I use MinGW toolchain CDT Internal

Comment: Consider adding `-mwindows` in your CDT/MinGW compile options: [Can g++ / minGW play nice with the Windows SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022112/can-g-mingw-play-nice-with-the-windows-sdk-is-visual-studio-the-only-option)

Comment: Added -mwindows compiler flag but no difference and still have those errors

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-mwindows` to the command line patterns field for the MinGW C++ linker worked for me (Project Settings > C/C++ Build > Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Command line patterns).

Screenshot of Settings window:

[image: Screenshot of Settings window]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).