# How does one compile a C program that includes the slpublic.h header file?

Tags: c, winapi

How does one use the `SLOpen()` function from `slpublic.h` in the Windows API?

**Update**

```
usr@DESKTOP-xxxxx  /c/users/usr/Desktop
$ cat main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <slpublic.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello world\n");
        HSLC ptr;
        SLOpen(&ptr);
        return 0;
}
```

```
usr@DESKTOP-xxxxx  /c/users/usr/Desktop
$ g++ main.cpp  -o app
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:9: error: 'HSLC' was not declared in this scope
    8 |         HSLC ptr;
      |         ^~~~
main.cpp:9:17: error: 'ptr' was not declared in this scope
    9 |         SLOpen(&ptr);
      |                 ^~~
main.cpp:9:9: error: 'SLOpen' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_lopen'?
    9 |         SLOpen(&ptr);
      |         ^~~~~~
      |         _lopen
usr@DESKTOP-xxxxx  /c/users/usr/Desktop
```

Are there any missing linking switches in the compile command?

Comment: What compiler exactly do you use? If it's gcc from msys2 or something, its headers may lack full support of Windows-specific stuff, including this one. I see similar errors with my msys2, but Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code) works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're building the correct file? That you really saved it before building? If you're doing the command `cat main.cpp` or `type main.cpp`, is it showing the file you expect?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes i am sure of the file

Comment: @yeputons the compiler of choice is `mingw-w64` from msys2, isn't there a way to use the header file or do i have to change the compiler?

Comment: Please type the file anyway, just to make *really* sure. And since the file is so short, please copy-paste (as text!) the full command to type the file, its output, followed by the command to build and the errors. All as one single large code-formated text-block.

Comment: Re "linking switches"? Are these compiler errors? The linker doesn't know about C or C++ scope. It ssems unclear which of C or C++ you want to use anyway.

Comment: @loaded_dypper You definitely need to install _something_, even "ucrt" version from msys2 does not include the correct header. Probably you need to install Windows SDK from Microsoft, but I'm not sure if gcc will play along, see some very old (and probably outdated) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2022112/767632).

Comment: You could do it using dynamic linking with the help of `LoadLibrary` but that would be a bit harder

Comment: @WeatherVane I want to use cpp but if it works in `c++` then it should also work in `c` right ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my bad forgot to add the header, but even with the header I still get the same error

Comment: I can [replicate](https://godbolt.org/z/aa4d8oT1e) the problem. [The `SLOpen` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/slpublic/nf-slpublic-slopen) only mentions the `slpublic.h` header file, which is found by the compiler (or you would get other errors). So I would argue that there's something missing from the documentation, more specifically another header file that needs to be included.

Comment: And [this overview of the `slpublic.h` header file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/slpublic/) doesn't mention the type `HSLC` anywhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if use *CL* (*msvc*) all is compile ok

Comment: `HSLC` should be defined near the top of `slpublic.h` as `typedef PVOID HSLC;`, if your copy of `slpublic.h` does not do that then you are using an outdated version and should update your Windows SDK. Otherwise, just define `HSLC` in your own code before using it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude MinGW/msys2 provide their own headers, not ones from Windows SDK provided by Microsoft. They sometimes miss stuff. If anything, that's not a documentation issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the errors you show are telling you:

```
$ g++ main.cpp  -o app
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
```

first, there's no error about finding `slpublic.h` include file, so it is found somewhere in your system.  It has been included correctly, but probably that file is not the one you need to include (see below)

```
main.cpp:8:9: error: 'HSLC' was not declared in this scope
    8 |         HSLC ptr;
      |         ^~~~
```

This error means that `HSLC` is nothing known to the compiler (probably it should be a type)  Most probable reason for this is that you have not read the documentation and have for some reason mispelled that name.  Or it can be that you have included the wrong `.h` file.

```
main.cpp:9:17: error: 'ptr' was not declared in this scope
    9 |         SLOpen(&ptr);
      |                 ^~~
```

Of course, if `HSLC` is not a valid type, the declaration for `ptr` has been ignored by the compiler, so this error will cancel too, when you correct the error above.

```
main.cpp:9:9: error: 'SLOpen' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_lopen'?
    9 |         SLOpen(&ptr);
      |         ^~~~~~
      |         _lopen
```

This error also means that `SLOpen` is nothing known to the compiler.  Are you sure that `slpublic.h` is the file you need to `#include`?  The file has been correctly included in your program, but most probably it is not the correct one.